# How to store mongoose timestamp in epoch timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I store all the timestamps (default createdAt, updatedAt and my custom Timestamp values) in the epoch timestamps?

Tried putting this in schema, but it is not working.

```
timestamps: {
      fieldType: Number,
      dateFunc: function () {
        return Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000); /* timestamp in seconds */
      }
    },
```

Comment: Why do you like to store the epoch timestamp? Store proper `Date` object!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be as simple as this:

```
timestamps: {
  fieldType: Date,
  default: () => Date.now()
}
```

You should store timestamps as `Date` value rather than epoch seconds (but still better than strings!). It makes your life easier.